# Spring - how can I check if user exists in database (Service+DAO layer)

Tags: java, spring

I'm making a web application (Virtual Clinic), I made DAO and Service layers for that and it works fine in Controller, but I don't know how can I check if entered login and password exist in my database? I want in order to application will redirect to Home.jsp if user exists in database, if not - then app will redirect to ErrorAuthentication.sjp for example. How can I do that?

Here is a code:

LoginController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView homePagePost(@ModelAttribute("user") User user)
{   
    setAppContext();         
    clinicService.checkAuthentication(user);

 // and now something like:
 //if (entered login and password are in database) {

 //return home;

 //}

 //else {

 //return errorAuthenticationPage;

 //}
    ModelAndView home = new ModelAndView("Home");
    return home;
}
```

Login.jsp:

```
<form action="/VirtualClinic/home.html" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Login"/>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
  <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

UserDaoImpl:

```
public void checkAuthentication(User user) {
    String query = "SELECT login, password FROM virtualclinic.user WHERE login=? AND password=?";
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try{
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, user.getLogin());
        ps.setString(2, user.getPassword());
        ResultSet out = ps.executeQuery();

    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            ps.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }// TODO Auto-generated met

}
```

ClinicServiceImpl:

```
public void checkAuthentication(User user) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("clinicconfig.xml");
    userDAO = ctx.getBean("userDAO", UserDAO.class);

    user.setLogin(user.getLogin());
    user.setPassword(user.getPassword());

    userDAO.checkAuthentication(user);

}
```

Comment: what attribute do you use to uniquely identify the user, email? username?

Comment: You need your checkAuthentication method in UserDao to return something meaningful. It can check to see if the user name provided exists and, if it does, that the (hashed) passwords match. If so it can return true. You can then return this result via checkAuthentication, and finally process it in homePagePost.

Comment: @Andonaeus: Ok I guess I get it, so I should do something like "if (rs.next()) { return true } else { return false }" in this method, right?

Comment: @dante That would work, assuming that login is a unique key.